# Flutter - Facing issue with Mailer package while sending email

Tags: flutter, mailer, blocked

This Siva. I am learning flutter and playing with it.
I came across "Mailer" package to send emails.
(https://pub.dev/packages/mailer)

Followed the example given at:
https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/blob/master/example/send_gmail.dart

On android, I am able to send emails (from Application) using a simulator (Virtual device).
But when users tries the APP (from India), I am getting email from google as

**Sign-in attempt was blocked**

I tried "Allowing less secure apps: ON" as suggested from some forums.
This also did not help.

Could you please help me if any other configuration is needed here.

I appreciate you support,
Thanks,
Siva

Comment: I was getting same although using correct username and password with less secure option but using one setting everything working fine now..  Go to Settings>Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Enable IMAP access , it will not show any error now